# Actionscript Dynamic Variables for object

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript, dynamic-variables

How can I create dynamic variable in ActionScript?

Example code:

```
import windows.nwindow;

for(var num:int = 0; num< 2; num++)
            {
                this["nWin"+num] = new nwindow();
                this["nWin"+num].width = 320;
                this["nWin"+num].height = 200;
                this["nWin"+num].title="window" + num;
                this["nWin"+num].open();
            }
```

When I run the above code it dispatch this error:

```
Error #1056: Cannot create property nWin0 on MultiWindow.
```

So, how can I use dynamic variable for this case here?

Comment: The answer below is correct, but I'm wondering what is the advantage in your program to having a dynamic member vs. an element in an array.  I.e., rather than this["nWin"+num], have this.myWindows[num]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use a dictionary to achieve this. eg-

```
        var dict:Dictionary = new Dictionary;
        for(var num:int = 0; num< 2; num++)
        {
            var str:String = "nWin"+num;
            dict[str] = new nwindow();
            dict[str].width = 320;
            dict[str].height = 200;
            dict[str].title="window" + num;
            dict[str].open();
        }
```

Comment: In this case an "Object" would have been enough. Dictionaries are used wherever the key is not a string. If however your key can be mapped to strings I guess an Object should be simpler.